Why does my timezone not update in embedded linux?
I have an embedded Linux with a write lock on all system folders (including /etc) and only one folder being freely writable, called /writable. /etc/localtime is a symbolic link that points to  /writable/localtime.
My (test) application changes the timezone by copying a different timezone file into the location at /writable/localtime, then calls tzset() and tries to read tzname.
However regardless of whether I copy the timezone information or turn the file into a symlink pointing elsewhere, tzset does neither change tzname, nor does it update the offsets (meaning using localtime yields the same results).
Only after restarting the application, the new timezone takes effect.
Why?

To the downvoter: The question only describes the phenomenon and does not include an MRI, because I answered the question myself to help whoever may come across the issue themselves. I didn't actively look for help, hence the 'question' (which is basically the prelude for the answer) does not contain code.

TL;DR
Use a combination of setenv, unsetenv and tzset to force it to do its job.
(Minimal) Example code:
#include <time.h>

int main(int, const char **)
{
    //Install new timezone file
    setenv("TZ", "UTC", 1);
    tzset();
    unsetenv("TZ");
    tzset();
    //Format time to check it worked.
}

What's going on?
This one had me puzzled for a good while, which is why I figured I'd share my findings with the community.
In the sources of glibc, I found that tzset performs two checks prior to doing its actual work.The first check is 'looking at the environment variable' (TZ).If set, the function compares the value with its (internally) cached value and if the two are equal (strcmp), tzset aborts there.
But this wasn't the case here, since the environment variable wasn't set at all.
The second check, after making sure that TZ wasn't set during the last call, compares whether the timezone file (/etc/localtime) has changed by evaluating its metadata (inode number, modification date, etc.).
And this is where the problem in the above scenario sits: You do not update /etc/localtime, you update where it points to and tzset doesn't look that far.
So, by using the above logic, tzset deduces, that there's nothing to be done.
By setting the environment variable and calling tzset, you update its internal buffers.tzset now knows, that you are using a custom timezone string and not the file.By unsetting the environmental variable in the next step, the first check returns false, because the cached timezone value (UTC) is different from the current timezone value (NULL) and the second check also yields false, because the environment variable had been used before, making it skip the file check altogether.
All of this only applies, if you cannot manipulate /etc/localtime directly, but need to manipulate the place it points to. Otherwise tzset would detect 'file has changed' as described above.
Regarding the 'when a new process is started, the correct timezone is used':
When starting a new process, the timezone (which had been changed prior to starting) is evaluated 'anew'.
The above workaround is only required for an already running processes.

It's a dirty hack. The basic knowledge missing here is that Timezone is a property of the process. Newly running process gets the new timezone. Old process keeps going on with the old one.

It's not pretty, I give you that, @0andriy. But the scenario is: The current process has changed the timezone file and now wants it reflected in its own routines. That didn't work. Just re-setting the environment variable once wouldn't have worked either. Hence the 'hack'. If tzset had just re-read the file upon being called, this question wouldn't exist.

tzset should be following symlinks to get file status. Is the modification time of the file changing when you copy the new timezone file to /writable/localtime? Do you have all the possible timezone files stored in the read-only filesystem? If so, you could change /writable/localtime to a symlink pointing to the timezone file in the read-only filesystem.

@0andriy Glibc tries to be clever and refresh the timezone data for running processes.

@IanAbbott, according to the source I found, it only looks at the symlink itself. And that symlink does, in fact, not change, leading to the described behavior. Changing /writable/localtime into a symlink makes no difference.

AFAICT, __tzfile_read calls internal versions of stat and fstat, not lstat, so it should be following symlinks. It doesn't really make sense for it not to follow symlinks.
